# Woocommerce quick checkout form

Tags: plugins, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a site powered by WordPress and using Woocommerce Plugin i want to add a custom quick checkout form on a single product page here is the reference see the image [image: Quick checkout form]

Can i make a custom form and place order? Any Solution???

Comment: Please do some and show some research from your side as what have you done to accomplish this. Without showing any effort it's difficult to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it by using `wc_create_order` here is the full code

`if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

```
$address = array(
    'first_name' => $_POST['fullname'],
    'email'      => $_POST['email'],
    'phone'      => $_POST['phone'],
    'address_1'  => $_POST['address'], 
    'city'       => $_POST['city'],
);

$order = wc_create_order();
$order->add_product( get_product( get_the_id() ), $_POST['quantity'] );
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
$order->set_payment_method( 'cod' );
$order->calculate_totals();
```

}`